# Changing the AzureDevOps trigger doesn't work (from build to build pipeline)

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, triggers, pipeline

I'm trying to trigger the build of pipeline B based on the build of pipeline A. This works, and I tested this on a feature branch before changing it to master. However, when I change the branch to master, it does NOT trigger on master, but still triggers on the feature branch.

I added the following to trigger pipeline B:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: test1
    source: test1
    branch: master
    project: project1
    trigger:
      branches:
      - master
      stages: 
        - buildPackageMaster
```

Previously, for testing purposes it was configured for a feature branch, as follows:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: test1
    source: test1
    branch: feature/DATA-24843
    project: project1
    trigger:
      branches:
      - feature/DATA-24843
      stages: 
        - buildPackageNonMaster
```

But it doesn't pick up the change I made. So it still triggers on a change in feature/DATA-24843, but not from master. Any ideas on why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try using 'refs/heads/master' instead of just master

Comment: That also triggered only from the previously defined feature branch. Creating an entire new branch and only putting the master branch in there (as referenced above) did work... Seems like a bug in azure-devops.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tested this problem. Please check the following two cases:

1. Make sure your changes are saved and run. If your changes are not saved, the system will not recognize them.
2. If you change the branch of pipeline B individually, click save, but not run, then this pipeline will be triggered, but the branch will not change. If we change pipeline B and click run, the branch of the triggered pipeline B will work as expected.

For a workaround, please make sure that the trigger branch of your pipeline B changes, and click save and run after the change. This will work as expected.

Comment: I did save and ran my changes but it never picks up the changes.. This case is also cross-project, so maybe that isn't working proper yet.